# Two, one dimensional arrays of integers that returns true

Tags: java, arrays

We have a Final exam that is coming up, it is proctored this is just a study question, but I am having issues with two arrays I wrote out when I put them into eclipse. I would like some insight that may help me on the test, thanks.

---

Write a Java function that accepts two one-dimensional arrays of integers and returns true if and only if all the integers in the first array are contained in the second, and all the integers in the second array are contained in the first

---

```
public class Two1dimensionalArraysMain 
{
    public boolean main(int []array1, int []array2) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {

                    if(array1[i]==array2[j]) 
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (array1[i] != array2[j])
                        return false;

            }
        return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe sort them and then compare in a single loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning `false` too early.

Here's what it looks like you're trying to do.  You look at each element X in `array1`.  Then you compare that one element to each element in `array2`.  If X equals any element in `array2`, you're good (so far) and you can look at the next element in `array1`.  But if X is different from every element in `array2`, then return `false`.

That's a good approach.  The problem is that you return false if X is different from **any** element in `array2`, not if it's different from **every** element.  This is because as soon as you see two elements that are different between the two arrays, you return `false` right away.

```
public boolean main(int []array1, int []array2) 
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
                if(array1[i]==array2[j]) 
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (array1[i] != array2[j])
                    return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

To fix this: You need to do the `return false` check **outside** the `for (int j...` loop.  There are a number of ways to do this, but my favorite is this:

1. Declare a `boolean` variable `found`.  You will initialize this to `false` before going through `array2`.
2. Before you `break`, set `found = true;`, to indicate that the element X in `array1` was found in `array2`.
3. After you're done going through `array2`, check `found`.  If it's `false`, then you know the whole function should return `false`.

Also, your `return true` is in the wrong place.  If you fix those two things, your method should work.

**EDIT:** I missed that the equality has to be two ways.  The above, with my suggestions, will return `true` if every element in `array1` is in `array2`, but not vice versa.  One simple update would be to write a helper method `allElementsAreIn` that uses two `int[]` arrays, and then call it twice, something like `allElementsAreIn(array1,array2) && allElementsAreIn(array2,array1)`.

By the way, don't call your function `main`.  That name should be used only for the main program, which must be `void` and take a `String[]` parameter.

P.S. I'm assuming that the purpose of the exercise is to learn the basics of loops and such.  In an actual production environment, it would be much simpler to use a `Set` as in amit's answer.

Comment: Thank you that is very explanative of the concept behind what they are imposing and the proper flow of the answer itself, I am hoping that they are looking for the general concept and that we understand that it should be two arrays in a nested for loops construct, but with 50 questions and 4 of these in about an hour I don't think they will be super picky as long as we are showing we picked up on the process involved. - If I could up vote  Iwould upvote all of you for the help thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Best solution in my opinion is to use set equality, if that's allowed.

```
public static boolean checkArraysContainSameElements(int[] array1, int[] array2) { 
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int x : array1) set1.add(x);
    Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int x : array2) set2.add(x);
    return set1.equals(set2);

}
```

Other than that, I refer to [@ajb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23506585/572670) to see what's wrong with the solution you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array and compare in the loop:

```
public boolean checkArrayEquality(int[] source, int[] target)
{
    Arrays.sort(source);
    Arrays.sort(target);

    if(source.length == target.length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < target.length; i++)
        {
            if(source[i] != target[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```